# Extracting values from dictionary keys - then combining into an object

Tags: json, swift, dictionary

I have a JSON response that I've parsed in Swift down to a single dictionary set of [String:Any]. I'm attempting to check each key for it's value, then add that value as a variable passed into the creation of a SteamFriend object.

```
for (key, value) in level3 {
    var avatar:URL!
    var personaname:String = ""
    var personastate:Int = 0
    var steamid:String = ""

    if key == "avatar" {
        if let avatarAsString = value as? String {
            let avatarAsURL = URL(string: avatarAsString)
            avatar = avatarAsURL
        }
    } else if key == "personaname" {
        if let personanameAsString = value as? String {
            personaname = personanameAsString
        }
    } else if key == "personastate" {
        if let personastateAsInt = value as? Int {
            personastate = personastateAsInt
        }
    } else if key == "steamid" {
        if let steamidAsString = value as? String {
            steamid = steamidAsString
        }
    }

    let createSteamFriend = SteamFriend(avatar: avatar, personaname: 
    personaname, personastate: personastate, steamid: steamid)
}
```

and the class for SteamFriend is

```
class SteamFriend {
var avatar: URL
var personaname: String
var personastate: Int
var steamid: String

init (avatar:URL, personaname:String, personastate: Int, steamid:String) {
    self.avatar = avatar
    self.personaname = personaname
    self.personastate = personastate
    self.steamid = steamid
}
```

}

When I run the above code I immediate get an error on the createSteamFriend line stating "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an object". I have run a print statement against each optional cast above, and I know that they are all returning values.

I'm sure there's a flaw in the logic of my code. I just can't for the life of me figure out the proper way to create the SteamFriend object.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line `let createSteamFriend = SteamFriend(...)` and check the values. Also, I'd think that you want to do that line outside (after) the for loop, and put the var declaration outside too (before the foor loop). Also what's the code for `SteamFriend(avatar:personaname:personastate: steamid:)`?

Comment: @larme I'll update the answer now to include the SteamFriend class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you redeclare the variables in each loop so the URL is `nil` unless the key `avatar` is found in the last iteration.

Anyway this is a very cumbersome way to enumerate a dictionary, just get the values for keys directly without a loop:

```
var avatar: URL!

if let avatarAsString = level3["avatar"] as? String {
    let avatarAsURL = URL(string: avatarAsString)
    avatar = avatarAsURL
}
let personaname = level3["personaname"] as? String ?? ""
let personastate = level3["personastate"] as? Int ?? 0
let steamid = level3["steamid"] as? String ? ""

let createSteamFriend = SteamFriend(avatar: avatar, personaname: 
personaname, personastate: personastate, steamid: steamid)
```

If the `avatar` parameter in the initializer is required (a non-optional type) I'd even write

```
guard let avatarAsString = level3["avatar"] as? String else { 
  // show an error message
  return
}
let avatar = URL(string: avatarAsString)!
```

Comment: Thanks man this was it. I was doing one too many for loops. After you mentioned this I immediately did a print on level3, and found that the last for loop was unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You are resetting your variables in your loop for each element.
So, once you found "avatar" you set your URL. Next element, You reset avatar to URL!.
Put your variables and let createSteamFriend outside your loop.

```
var avatar:URL!
var personaname:String = ""
var personastate:Int = 0
var steamid:String = ""

for (key, value) in level3 {

if key == "avatar" {
    if let avatarAsString = value as? String {
        let avatarAsURL = URL(string: avatarAsString)
        avatar = avatarAsURL
    }
} else if key == "personaname" {
    if let personanameAsString = value as? String {
        personaname = personanameAsString
    }
} else if key == "personastate" {
    if let personastateAsInt = value as? Int {
        personastate = personastateAsInt
    }
} else if key == "steamid" {
    if let steamidAsString = value as? String {
        steamid = steamidAsString
    }
}

}
let createSteamFriend = SteamFriend(avatar: avatar, personaname: 
personaname, personastate: personastate, steamid: steamid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your `avatar` is nil because you are creating `createSteamFriend` instance four-time and values come singly at a time.

Why you run loop if you get a single dictionary? try to get the values from dictionary directly don't use the loop and unnecessary if else conditions.

```
var avatar = URL()

if let avatarAsString = level3["avatar"] as? String {
    let avatarAsURL = URL(string: avatarAsString)
    avatar = avatarAsURL
}
let personaname = level3["personaname"] as? String
let personastate = level3["personastate"] as? Int 
let steamid = level3["steamid"] as? String 

let createSteamFriend = SteamFriend(avatar: avatar, personaname: 
            personaname, personastate: personastate, steamid: steamid)
```